# Can't figure out how to isolate term

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$$
b^2 = x^2 + (x - c)^2 - a^2
$$

And I want to express the formula as $$ x = \cdots$$
After expanding the parentheses, I get to
$$
b^2 = x^2 + x^2 - 2xc + c^2 - a^2
$$
which I can transform into:
$$
b^2 +a^2 - c^2 = 2x^2 - 2xc 
$$
But there I get stuck. How can I isolate $x$? Step-by-step details would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, $(x-c)^2 = x^2 - 2cx + c^2$. Furthermore, observe that you have a quadratic in $x$. Do you think the ABC-formula might be useful?

Comment: Do you know the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation)?

Comment: ABC formula, had not concidered that yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have: $$b^2 +a^2 - c^2 = 2x^2 - xc$$ which can be written as: $$-2x^2+ xc+b^2 +a^2 - c^2 =0.$$
For simplicity, we let $k=b^2+a^2-c^2$ and so our equation becomes: $$-2x^2+xc+k=0.$$
This is a quadratic equation, and to solve for $x$ use the quadratic formula which says that if $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is a second order equation then its solution is given by: $$
    x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac\ }}{2a}. $$